# How to ask a practice book question and apology?

Tags: discussion, support, homework-and-exercises, specific-question

I wanted to know how to ask the question from my practice book

I add the homework tag and obviously I myself want to know only the concept part and I also give information about what I did and how I approached the problem
But still my Question was put Off-topic
if I went wrong in the way of asking the question then I am Sorry for that ,
I am not that good a communicative english and I completely say and agree 100% that I only require some concept which I may be missing in my approach

If anyone can tell how to ask these problems then it would be really helpful.

I have already read the meta post but still not getting it

and once again sorry for the bad way of asking my doubt

I love physics and also feel it and completely go with concept only thing i am not understanding is how to convey what i want to know
really I have read the help center and all other stuff and I am trying my best to improve my asking skill in english
I am a school going student and want to understand the concepts even more by solving the questions itself

So I am very sorry for hurting the community I never wanted the value or any thing like that i just needed the concept I wrote the whole question as I thought I would not be very good at asking the question and express my views in English

I would and I promise that definitely try to improve my communication skills and the way I ask

Comment: Hi, these questions aren't on topic on physics.SE however we are in the process of developing a site here:  http://physicsproblems.nfshost.com/ where homework like questions are on topic provided you show your working so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your three questions ([here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290344/a-projectile-question), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290337/a-question-of-pulley-and-monkey) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290325/a-question-of-projectile)) do not really *show* the work you have been putting in - maybe you can be a bit more explicit and write down more clearly and in more detail what your attempts are. Also, questions like "I need to know how to approach this problem" are usually not received as conceptual questions and often seen unfit.

One thing that is important to me - you did not hurt anyone's feelings. No one here is going to be insulted or mad because they feel a question might not fit within the policy of the page.

Comment: I think your second paragraph is especially useful here. Thanks for it.